# Asp .NET Web API - Configurar rutas especificas

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Estoy desarrollando un Web API con C#. Se me solicitó que las URLs de acceso a los diferentes metodos sea con el siguiente formato:

```
https://urlPrincipal/integracion-lis/api/v1/nombreMetodo
```

Donde: urlPrincipal contendrá el dominio configurado en producción y nombreMetodo será variable según el método a consumir.

No logro configurar mis rutas para contemplar ese formato, actualmente en la clase `WebApiConfig.cs` tengo lo siguiente **(arroja error 404)**:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultRoute",
    routeTemplate: "integracion-lis/api/v1/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

El controller y el action:

```
public class TestController : ControladorBase
{
    [Route("muestras-validadas")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult ObtenerClientes(bool soloActivos, string idONombre = null)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, base.GenerarRespuestaConResultado<IEnumerable<int>>(new int[] { 1, 2 }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Instancia.AgregarError(ex, $"Controlador: {ControladorHelper.ObtenerNombreControlador(this)} - Accion: {ControladorHelper.ObtenerNombreAccion(this)}");

            return base.Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, base.GenerarRespuestaConErrorGenerico());
        }
    }
}
```

La URL que estoy intentando consumir para ese método es la siguiente:

```
http://localhost:62344/v1/integracion-lis/api/v1/muestras-validadas
```

**Nota:** `localhost:62344` es la URL de desarrollo montada en IIS Express al ejecutar el proyecto en Visual Studio. El proyecto compila y corre sin errores.

**Nota 2:** el ID opcional será necesario porque algunos métodos a consumir recibirán ese parámetro como una parte de la ruta.

Alguna ayuda de cómo configurarlo correctamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy algo añejo en `C#`, pero lo que me servía no era tocar el **WebApiConfig**, - *de hecho ese config.Routes.MapHttpRoute lo dejaba por defecto* - sino que era especificar las rutas en cada método que creaba

```
[RoutePrefix("aintegracion-lis/api/v1/")]
public class Controller : ApiController
{
    [Route("list")]
    public IEnumerable<T> Get() { ... }

    [Route("item/{id:int}")]
    public T Get(int id) { ... }    
}
```

De esta forma puedes crear las rutas que quieras y exponerlas como quieras :D

Ahora ten en cuenta que al momento de configurar un parámetro opcional debe incluir el símbolo *?* de esta manera

```
Route("item/{id?}")]
```

Nos comentas si te sirve! :D

Comment: Excelente Paulo, funciono perfecto! Muchas gracias.